# Агрегация и ранжирование по DataFrame со смещением

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, анализ-данных

Есть DataFrame:

```
demo = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2009-06', '2009-06', '2009-06', '2009-06',
                              '2009-07', '2009-07', '2009-07', '2009-07',
                              '2009-08', '2009-08', '2009-08', '2009-08'],
                     'group': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2], 
                     'value_1': [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 25, 20, 15, 35, 30, 25, 20],
                     'value_2': [45, 40, 35, 30, 100, 110, 120, 130, 10, 20, 30, 40],
                    })
demo
    date  group value_1 value_2
0   2009-06 1   10  45
1   2009-06 1   15  40
2   2009-06 2   20  35
3   2009-06 2   25  30
4   2009-07 1   30  100
5   2009-07 1   25  110
6   2009-07 2   20  120
7   2009-07 2   15  130
8   2009-08 1   35  10
9   2009-08 1   30  20
10  2009-08 2   25  30
11  2009-08 2   20  40
```

На выходе нужно получить:

```
demo_full = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2009-06', '2009-06', '2009-06', '2009-06',
                              '2009-07', '2009-07', '2009-07', '2009-07',
                              '2009-08', '2009-08', '2009-08', '2009-08'],
                     'group': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2], 
                     'value_1': [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 25, 20, 15, 35, 30, 25, 20],
                     'value_2': [45, 40, 35, 30, 100, 110, 120, 130, 10, 20, 30, 40],
                     'rank_1': [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                     'rank_2': [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                    })
demo_full

    date group value_1 value_2 rank_1 rank_2
0   2009-06 1   10  45  NaN NaN
1   2009-06 1   15  40  NaN NaN
2   2009-06 2   20  35  NaN NaN
3   2009-06 2   25  30  NaN NaN
4   2009-07 1   30  100 0.0 1.0
5   2009-07 1   25  110 0.0 1.0
6   2009-07 2   20  120 1.0 0.0
7   2009-07 2   15  130 1.0 0.0
8   2009-08 1   35  10  1.0 0.0
9   2009-08 1   30  20  1.0 0.0
10  2009-08 2   25  30  0.0 1.0
11  2009-08 2   20  40  0.0 1.0
```

Где значение для `rank_{i}` считается следующим образом: мы группируем по дате (с точностью до месяца), группе, смотрим, например среднее и далее присваиваем ранг каждой группе - чем выше среднее, тем выше ранг и наоборот. Далее данный ранг нужно присвоить не текущему месяцу, а следующему, то есть у нас сдвиг на 1 месяц.

Ранг считаю следующим образом:

```
demo.groupby(['date', 'group'])['value_1'].mean().groupby('date').apply(lambda x: np.argsort(x))

date     group
2009-06  1        0
         2        1
2009-07  1        1
         2        0
2009-08  1        1
         2        0
```

1. Как это реализовать?
2. Можно ли реализовать при помощи методов `groupby` и `shift`?
3. Можно ли задать гибкость в реализации, чтобы была возможность использовать разные промежутки для смещения, например неделя, 2 месяца, год и тд?
4. Можно ли это распараллелить? У меня есть 8 ядер.

Comment: как-то странно у вас присваиваются ранги, раз вы группируете и по группе и по месяцу. в результирующем df у вас ранги повторяются? почему?

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы ранги были уникальные в рамках одного месяца для каждого года. То есть на основе информации за июнь 2009, я расставляю ранги для июля 2009. На основе информации за июль 2009, я расставляю ранги для августа 2009. Если бы `date` содержала день, то в `groupby` я бы писал так: `demo.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно преобразовать столбец `date` --> `Period[M]`, это позволит использовать `+1`, чтобы сдвинуться на месяц вперед:

```
demo["date"] = pd.to_datetime(demo["date"]).dt.to_period("M")

grp = demo.assign(date=demo["date"]+1).groupby(['date', 'group'])

r1 = grp['value_1'].mean().groupby("date").apply(np.argsort).to_frame(name="rank_1")
r2 = grp['value_2'].mean().groupby("date").apply(np.argsort).to_frame(name="rank_2")

res = demo.set_index(["date", "group"]).join(r1).join(r2).reset_index()
```

---

результат:

```
In [96]: res
Out[96]:
       date  group  value_1  value_2  rank_1  rank_2
0   2009-06      1       10       45     NaN     NaN
1   2009-06      1       15       40     NaN     NaN
2   2009-06      2       20       35     NaN     NaN
3   2009-06      2       25       30     NaN     NaN
4   2009-07      1       30      100     0.0     1.0
5   2009-07      1       25      110     0.0     1.0
6   2009-07      2       20      120     1.0     0.0
7   2009-07      2       15      130     1.0     0.0
8   2009-08      1       35       10     1.0     0.0
9   2009-08      1       30       20     1.0     0.0
10  2009-08      2       25       30     0.0     1.0
11  2009-08      2       20       40     0.0     1.0
```